# How do I set the value of a jquery slider on load if it's already set

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have a jquery slider and a textbox that stores the value. I'm running an asp.net application and want to load the textbox with the value if one is already stored and have the slider reflect the value. I'm thinking that a simple if statement in the jquery would do it, but i'm unfamiliar with the function.

Here is my current jquery:

```
    $("#cultureSlider").slider({
    value: 50,
    min: 1,
    max: 100,
    step: 1,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $(".cultureScore").val("" + ui.value);
    }
});
```

I would think something like this would work (but it doesn't):

```
    $("#cultureSlider").slider({
    if($(".cultureScore").val() == 50){
       value: 50,
    } else {
       value: $(".cultureScore").val(),
    }
    min: 1,
    max: 100,
    step: 1,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $(".cultureScore").val("" + ui.value);
    }
});
```

Comment: If `.cultureScore` is equal to 50, you set it to the value of `.cultureScore`, and if not, you do the same thing?  I think you're making it more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: By seeing if it's equal to 50, I'm checking if the value is the default value or if it's the value I've loading into the textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your syntax is wrong... try either an inlined if (forgot the technical term) or performing the calculation outside the slider instantiation.

### Method one

```
$("#cultureSlider").slider({
    value: ($(".cultureScore").val() == 50 ? 50 : $(".cultureScore").val()),
    min: 1,
    max: 100,
    step: 1,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $(".cultureScore").val("" + ui.value);
    }
});
```

### Method two

```
var scoreVal = 0;
if($(".cultureScore").val() == 50)
    scoreVal = 50;
else
    scoreVal = $(".cultureScore").val();

$("#cultureSlider").slider({
    value: scoreVal,
    min: 1,
    max: 100,
    step: 1,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $(".cultureScore").val("" + ui.value);
    }
});
```

Comment: It's called the ternary operator :-)

Comment: @Clive thank you! I just couldn't remember it for the life of me :P

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure an `if` statement is invalid where you've got it, and I think your check is redundant anyway, whether the `if` results in `TRUE` or `FALSE` you're always going to use `$(".cultureScore").val()`:

```
$("#cultureSlider").slider({
  value: $(".cultureScore").val(),
  min: 1,
  max: 100,
  step: 1,
  slide: function (event, ui) {
    $(".cultureScore").val("" + ui.value);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this:

```
var myVal = ($(".cultureScore").val() == 50) ? 50 : $(".cultureScore").val();
$("#cultureSlider").slider({
    value: myVal,
.
.
.
```